# glyphicons inside inputs and inside alerts

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Hello I'm having a hard time trying to put a glyphicon inside input tags, I've tried several codes from here and other sites but still can't get it..
this is what I have:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cedula">Cedula:</label>
    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Numero De Cedula" required="true"                                        autofocus="true" maxlength="9">
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my css file:

```
/* enable absolute positioning */
.inner-addon {
  position: relative;
}

/* style glyph */
.inner-addon .glyphicon {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* align glyph */
.left-addon .glyphicon  { left:  0px;}
.right-addon .glyphicon { right: 0px;}

/* add padding  */
.left-addon input  { padding-left:  30px; }
.right-addon input { padding-right: 30px; }
```

BUT I keep getting this weird symbol outside the input:

[image: Input tag]
and following the Bootstrap documentation I'm trying to implement the glyphicon inside the alert box:

```
if( $errores !== ""){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">'; 
    echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>';
    echo $errores; 
    echo '</div>';
}
```

but again weird symbol appears:
[image: Alert box glyphicon error]

Comment: What is your encoding type ? Better use UTF-8 I suppose.

Comment: hello I have <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: It may be a problem with the import of the bootstrap library, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20563/

Comment: But the other bootstrap components are working fine =/ @VincentG

Comment: Maybe try to reupload a full version of the library in your source code

Comment: using the CDN link instead of my local solved the alert box problem but there's the input error still showing the glyphicon outside the input @VincentG

Comment: You want this ? https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20565/

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want... and it worked fine BUT the glyphicon is showing up in the left part of the input and I can't move it to the right @VincentG

Comment: Change the position value in my code : https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20566/

Answer (score 0):

Just use only this (no additional css needed):

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label class="control-label" >Cedula:</label>          
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Numero De Cedula" required="true"                                        autofocus="true" maxlength="9">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi it does show the glyphicon but just not in the right position but a litle bit outside the input

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></i></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Numero De Cedula" required="true"                                        autofocus="true" maxlength="9">
 </div>
```